# Modal popup with redirect button

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

I am sure this is simple, but I am not sure how to achieve this in a simple manner. When users go to mysite.com I would like for a modal to popup first. Inside the modal I need to have three buttons, each button points to a different URL when pushed.

I have a basic popup that works fine, howevert I am not sure how to add in the button and also style it with CSS.

Any help is greatly appreciated. The reason for the usage of the one below is it worked for me and it retained a session cookie.

```
function setSessionCookie (c_name, value)
{
    document.cookie= c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie (c_name)
{
    if (document.cookie.length>0)
    {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != - 1)
        {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape (document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }

    return "";
}


if (getCookie("bannerDisplayed").length <= 0)
{
    result = confirm("Please select one on the locations you would like to visit."); 

    if (result != true) document.location="about:blank";
    else
    {
        setSessionCookie("bannerDisplayed", "true");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't style a confirm box as it is default with the browser. However, you can use javascript to create your own custom modal. I would look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) framework (also required jquery for the modal and other JS specific stuff).

Here is a bootply of a modal example. You can change the CSS to meet your needs and also update the click handlers of your 3 buttons (along with the content):

http://www.bootply.com/120896

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-default" id="openBtn" href="#">Open modal</a>

  <div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h3>Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>My modal content here…</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn" id="opt1" data-dismiss="modal">Option 1</button>
          <button class="btn" id="opt2" data-dismiss="modal">Option 2</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="opt3" data-dismiss="modal">Option 3</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#openBtn').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal("show");
});

$('#opt1').click(function () {
  alert("Opt1 clicked.");
});

$('#opt2').click(function () {
  alert("Opt2 clicked.");
});

$('#opt3').click(function () {
  alert("Opt3 clicked.");
});
```

Comment: Perfect thanks for the example I can work with this. One thing how do I add a session cookie into this?

Comment: You should just be able to call getCookie and setSessionCookie as you were doing before. Hard to give a more specific example as I don't know what you are trying to achieve. If you need to set the session cookie when the user makes a selection in the modal, then that would go into one of the click handlers for the options. You can also check the cookie before you show the modal if you need to (similar to what you are doing above with your confirm box).

Comment: The above JS I downloaded and modified slightly to my needs. I want users to only be prompted once for the modal until they close their browser.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example of the markup for your modal window? You should be able to add any markup inside this, so if you are linking to 3 different URLs, you just need 3 `a` tags, that link to those sites. You can style these the same way you style any `a` tag.

Comment: What I did was place the .js file at the top of my HTML to be loaded first.

Comment: The JS file will be using some HTML to display the popup - what does this HTML look like?